# Infinitely Often vs Almost Always

Tags: probability, analysis

Let $A_n$ be an event ($n \in \mathbb{N}$). Why is it that $x$ occuring for all but finitely many $n$ be a subset of $x$ occuring for infinitely many $n$? What if $x \in A_{2k}$, then $x$ will  be occuring for infinitely many $n$, but not be occuring for all but finitely many $n$?

Comment: Yes, it is, in the infinitely many $A_{n}$ for $n=2,4,6,\ldots$.

Comment: It *is* in infinitely many $A_n$: Namely, $$x \in A_2, x \in A_4, x \in A_6, x \in A_8, \dots$$

Comment: $x$ is in infinitely many $A_n$'s.  (More precisely, it's in $A_n$ for infinitely many $n$'s.)  What makes you think it isn't?

Comment: I updated my question, I didn't really ask what I wanted at first!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"For all but finitely many $n, x\in E_n$" means that the subset of $\Bbb N$ for which $x\notin E_n$ is true is finite. "For infinitely many $n, x\in E_n$" means the subset of $\Bbb N$ for which $x\in E_n$ is true is infinite, i.e, not finite. Note this is different from the previous assertion, as you just have been shown, but the previous assertion implies the last.

**ADD** The above definition comes up when defining limit superiors and inferior of sets, namely $$E^\ast=\limsup E_n=\{x:x\in E_n\text{ for infinitely many } n\}$$ $$E_\ast=\liminf E_n=\{x:x\in E_n\text{ for all but finitely many } n\}$$

The above discussion implies that $E_\ast\subseteq E^\ast$. One can show, on the other hand, that $$E^\ast =\bigcap_{n\geqslant 1}\bigcup_{k\geqslant n}E_k$$ $$E_\ast =\bigcup_{n\geqslant 1}\bigcap_{k\geqslant n}E_k$$

The above shouldn't be too surprising: if $x$ is in $E_n$ for all but finitely many, we can choose large enough $M$ so that $\{M,M+1,\ldots\}$ doesn't contain said finite set, so $x$ will be in $E_M,E_{M+1},\ldots$ i.e. in $\bigcap_{k\geqslant M}E_k$; so in $E_\ast$. Conversely, $x\in E_\ast$ i.e. $ x\in \bigcap_{k\geqslant n}E_k$ for some $n=1,2,\ldots$ implies $x$ is in all but finitely many $E_m$, precisely, in all $E_m$ for $k\geqslant n$, except maybe the finitely many $E_1,\ldots,E_{n-1}$. I leave the proof for $E^\ast$ to you.

Comment: Ah, I had a bit of a problem with my logic. Thanks!!

Comment: Some authors say "ultimately" to mean "for all but finitely many".  I find this more elegant.