# How can I prove almost surely divergence statement?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, convergence-divergence

I'm currently studying probability thoery and stucked in this problem.

I need to show below statement. I don't know where can I start to solve.

I think It might be easy problem but, I cannot find any solution.

How to prove both way of below statement.

$X_n\rightarrow \infty \ a.e.$  iff $\forall M>0 \ s.t. P(X_n<M \ i.o.)=0$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any $M > 0$ we have $$\begin{align}
P(X_n \lt M \ \  i.o.) \gt 0 &\iff P(\omega 
:\liminf_{n\to\infty} X_n(\omega) \le M) \gt 0 \\ &\iff P(\omega:\lim_{n\to\infty}X_n(\omega) = \infty) < 1
\end{align}$$

Comment: Do you mean to have a $\lim \inf$ instead of a $\lim \sup$? If $X_n = (-1)^n$ then $X_n < 0$ i.o. but $\lim \sup X_n = 1$.

Comment: @RhysSteele oops, yes, of course, Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To prove this you translate the corresponding statement about real sequences. A real sequence $(x_n)$ diverges to infinity if and only if for all $M$ there exists $N$ such that $x_n\ge M$ whenever $n\ge N$. Using the 'i.o.' and 'a.a.' language, this means for all $M$, $x_n\ge M$ almost always.

Translate this into event language:

$$\{ X_n\to\infty\} = \bigcap_M\{ X_n \ge M\ \text{a.a.}\},$$

and we can take the intersection over integer $M$. Notice that $B_M:=\{ X_n \ge M\ \text{a.a.}\}$ form a decreasing family of events. Therefore $P(X_n\to\infty)=1$ if and only if$^\color{red}*$ $P(B_M)=1$ for all $M$, which holds iff $P(B_M^c)=0$ for all $M$. To finish the proof, observe that $$B_M^c=\{X_n<M\ \text{i.o.}\}.$$

---

$\color{red}*$: $P(X_n\to\infty)=P(\cap_M B_M)=\lim_M P(B_M)$ by continuity from above [ see [The intersection of all events in a sequence has probability $\lim \limits _{k \to \infty} P(A_k)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1532850/215011) ]. Since $P(B_M)$ is a decreasing sequence, if $\lim P(B_M)=1$ we must have $P(B_M)=1$ for every $M$. Conversely, if $P(B_M)=1$ for every $M$ then $\lim P(B_M)=1$.

Comment: what does a.a. means?

Comment: @someeed a.a. means *amost always*, i.e. for all but finitely many $n$. 'Almost always' is to liminf as 'infinitely often' is to limsup. See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/635320/215011

Comment: I'm not sure about why (→∞)=1  if and only if ()=1 for all . Could you explain this more??